# phonegap как распознавать штрих коды

Tags: android, phonegap

Есть ли решение для phonegap чтобы фотографировать штрих коды и на лету их распознавать?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск библиотек -- оффтопик на нашем сайте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Есть такая замечательная библиотека как `QuaggaJS`.   Сайт
  [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/)
- Phonegap/barcodescanner [github](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

Comment: да да с помощью нее и сделал